# Command To Check If Users In /etc/passwd Exist In A Different File

Tags: scripting, command, aix, passwd

Is it possible to query the /etc/passwd file to view all user UIDS less than 200 and to check if those users are within a file such as /etc/ftpusers?

So far, I have managed to craft the command below which lists out all users with a UID lower than 200, but I am not sure how to check if those listed users are within the /etc/ftpusers file.

```
grep -Ev "^\+" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($3 < 200) {print $1}'
```

If any users are not in the file, I need the difference to be outputted. I have tried to use a for statement but it has not worked well.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am working with AIX, apologies for the confusion, I have removed the Linux tag just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `aix diff` have the same option as `GNU diff` but in my `linux` this when executed with `ksh` (the default shell in `aix`) work:

```
diff -I "^#" --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" <(awk -F: '$3 < 200  {print $1}' /etc/passwd) /etc/ftpusers
```

---

If the `diff` command differs try with a loop:

```
for u in $(awk -F":" '$3 < 200 {print $1}' /etc/passwd); do
        count=$(grep -scx "$u" /etc/ftpusers)
        [ "$count" -gt 0 ] || echo "$u"
done
```

I have tested it whit `ksh` and it work.

I also have checked the `grep` options available in the `grep` distributed whit `aix` and it support both `-c` for counting and `-s` to suppress error message.

Comment: Hi DanieleGrassini, thank you very much for the feedback, when trying to run the diff command I get the following error: diff: illegal option -- I
diff: two filename arguments required

Comment: and when I try to run the for loop, I get the following error: bash: : command not found

Comment: I suppose you get the error `bash: command not found` because you does not have `bash` installed. Can you try to run the script with this shabang : `#!/bin/ksh`?

Comment: @Help which `shell` do you use? is not `ksh` under `aix`? Do you have another one as default?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, awesome, running the script with the #! paramter works well, is there a way of running that command/script in a one liner? I tried the following, but it did not work: for u in $(awk -F: '$3 < 200 {print $1}' /etc/passwd); do count=$(grep -scx "$u" /etc/ftpusers)[ "$count" -gt 0 ] || echo "$u"; done

Comment: Im happy that it work. I think is better to write it in a script and call it when needed. But if you like to type that all the time, in a one-liners, put a: `;` after the assignmente to `count` Eg:`count=$(...);`

Comment: Thank you very much!!